# Since nvidia460 is installed one monitor is there

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, kde

I have a two monitor screen connected, but since the update of the Nvidia 460 I can only use one monitor, and the other monitor is black. When I reset it to Nouveau both screens are there. What can I do to get this back?

[image]

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 531mm x 299mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x720      59.94    50.00  
   1152x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       59.94    59.93  

# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.82

Section "ServerLayout"

# Removed Option "Xinerama" "0"
# Removed Option "Xinerama" "1"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" 2049 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PLX2483H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PLX2481H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     55.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1650"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1650"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On, AllowGSYNC=Off}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: 1920x1080_60_0 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "HDMI-1: 1920x1080_60 +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-3"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0 {AllowGSYNC=Off}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Extensions"
    Option         "(null)" "Disable"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my three screen setup. Surprisingly, the solution was to change the refresh frequency of one of the screens. The only way I could get all 3 screens to work was to set one of them to 59.xx Hz instead of 60Hz. I'm not sure why this happens, and the logs didn't seem to help.

Comment: oke but where can i set these settings ? nvidia they talk about absolute lol but thats wasn't working i can see my mouse over there thats all :)

Comment: so as you see i tried several times But nothing is worked. Nvidia update and xserver update gives this results before everything was fine

Comment: problem solves I simple wiped the xorg conf en reboot the machine :) very strange

Comment: Well, I guess there was something odd in your configuration. For what I'm concerned, you can change the refresh rate with xrandr or even with Ubuntu's GUI display settings. Note that some displays do not have the option to change the refresh rate.

Comment: Yes for some reason it did, but it was after an update of the nvidia and xserver. I have copied now the screen with the right configuration in case off :)